# in java how to pass multiple values from one class to anther using property?

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn java.
so here is what I am trying to do. I created a project in `intelij` & in there I'm trying get  `usrename` and password  from a file & use it in a class.
after searching for quite a time I came to know that `util.property` can do the needful. So I created a class to get the property.

```
public class Login {

    public String[] getLoginValues() throws IOException{
        String token = "";

        Properties prop=new Properties();
        String LoginFileName="login.properties";

        InputStream inputStream =getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(LoginFileName);
        if(inputStream!= null){
              prop.load(inputStream);
        }
        else{
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Property File"+LoginFileName+"not found in the classpath");

        }
            Date time= new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            System.out.println("Created at"+time);

        //get property values & print it out
       String userName=prop.getProperty("user.name");
        String password=prop.getProperty("password");
        String apiUrl=prop.getProperty("api.url");
}
```

Now I want the values -

> username,password, & apiurl

to be returned. but as you all know it cannot return multiple values

I want to use the values from login class to be used in my main class where I use them.
Here is the code for main class -

```
public class AutomationCount {
                //  login lg=new login();
    protected static String token = "";
    protected static String userName = ;//username
    protected static String password = ;//password
    protected static String apiUrl = ;//apiUrl
```

So what is that I need to do out there. Can you please help me.

Comment: make a class that contains these fields and then pass the class object

Comment: return  a map object with your values.

Comment: i didn't understand i have gathered the string values. then can't i call them just by creating an object of Login class in main class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options to solve this problem. Some are a better idea than others, but it depends on your situation. Some of these options include:

1) return a string array where each position in the array is a specific property

```
String results = new String[3];
results[0] = userName;
results[1] = password;
results[2] = apiUrl;
return results;
```

2) return an instance of a Credentials class such as:

```
public class Credentials {
    public String userName;
    public String password;
    public String apiUrl;
}
```

3) return the Properties object that you already have

4) return a map of the properties

```
Map<String, String> credentials = new HashMap<String, String>();
credentials.put("userName", userName);
credentials.put("password", password);
credentials.put("apiUrl", apiUrl);
return credentials;
```

Alternatively, your Login class could read the values in its constructor and provide getter methods to retrieve them individually like this:

```
public class Login {
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String apiUrl;

    public Login() throws IOException{
        String token = "";

        Properties prop=new Properties();
        String LoginFileName="login.properties";

        InputStream inputStream =getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(LoginFileName);
        if(inputStream!= null){
            prop.load(inputStream);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Property File"+LoginFileName+"not found in the classpath");

        }
        Date time= new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println("Created at"+time);

        //get property values & print it out
        userName=prop.getProperty("user.name");
        password=prop.getProperty("password");
        apiUrl=prop.getProperty("api.url");
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getApiUrl() {
        return apiUrl;
    }
}
```